# Purpose of "readonly" in C#? (Is this a loophole?)

Tags: c#, readonly

What is the purpose of making a field `readonly` in C#?

It doesn't actually seem to prevent modification of the field:

```
public struct Struct
{
    public readonly int Value;
    public Struct(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var s = new Struct(1);
        Debug.Assert(s.Value == 1, "Read-only field is 1");
        s = new Struct(2);
        Debug.Assert(s.Value == 2, "Read-only field written!");
    }
}
```

Is this considered a loophole, or is it by design?
And given that the field can be modified so easily, when would I benefit from making a field `readonly`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this considered a loophole, or is it by design?

It's by design.

It prevents the field itself from being modified directly (either inside or outside the struct), but that doesn't mean you can't replace the whole value of the variable (`s` in this case) with a new `Struct` value.

It's definitely less useful with structs than with classes - particularly as the replacement of the "whole value" may well not be atomic - but it's still useful IMO.

To put it another way... you can think of integers as immutable values, right? But this code is still valid:

```
int x = 10;
x = 20;
```

That changes the value of `x` - it doesn't change the meaning of 10.

Comment: +1 for classes, I think that's the real anwswer. I was thinking of structs when I wrote the question and completely forgot about classes...

Comment: Regarding integers being immutable... I don't really think of them as being immutable (they're obviously modifiable) but your point is taken.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty useful for structs which in general should be immutable, and declaring all their fields as `readonly` will make absolutely sure you don't mutate them.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: It makes sure you don't mutate them *within* a value, but it doesn't mean that you won't observe "half the value" being replaced as part of a "whole value replacement" operation. I'd definitely still advocate making structs readonly, but you need to be aware of the limitation.

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, an integer *isn't* modifiable. You can't make 10 mean something else. You can change the value of a variable which previously held the value 10, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's in the eye of the beholder. The sentence "make 10 mean something else" doesn't make much sense if you think about it a bit...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'd argue that's *because* we're so used to integers being immutable. Speaking about mutability of value types is always a bit tricky, to be honest. Even a value with just `readonly` fields can still replace itself wholesale in a method, as `this` is a `ref` variable within value type members. (I try to avoid using this feature, but I've recently found *one* example where it's useful.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's less tricky in C or C++, where mutability is explicitly guaranteed... so in C/C++ a `const int` is immutable whereas an `int` isn't. That's why I have a hard time agreeing "integers are immutable"... they can be easily modified, but obviously the *meaning* of a particular representation of them (like 10) is bound to that representation. (So calling the *meaning* "immutable" doesn't make much sense, of course it is.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: You say "they can easily be modified" - what can be modified, exactly? For reference types, it's easy to talk about the "what" - it's "the object itself". For value types such as `int`, you can't change the fields within the value, but you can change the value of the variable itself. Put it this way: I could definitely create a different version of `DateTime` where `AddDays` changed the value, rather than returning a new value. If I have a variable `x` of type `DateTime`, there's no `x.Foo()` method I can call which will change that value - so it makes sense to call it immutable.

Comment: @JonSkeet: "what can be modified, exactly?" -- It's actually simpler than that, you're thinking too hard I think. :) If you have a variable `x` of some value type, and you say `var y = x` if it's a value type (or `var y = x.Clone()` if it's a reference type) to make a copy of its value at that point in time, then when I say "x can be modified", I mean that there is *something* you can do which can subsequently make `x.Equals(y)` become false. If there is, then `x` is mutable. If this is possible for *some* `x` of that type, then `x`'s *type* is mutable. Obviously, then, `int` isn't immutable.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The point is that I didn't say that `x` can't be modified - it clearly can. I said that the *value* can't be modified. I think it's useful to distinguish between a variable and its value. The way you've phrased it, there is no such thing as an immutable type. For example, `string` is widely regarded as being immutable. Yet I can write: `x = "fred"; y = x; x = "other";`. (Change the middle statement to use `Clone()` if you want, it won't change anything.) That's "something" you can do to make `x.Equals(y)` become false. Therefore `string` is mutable according to your definition.

Comment: (I believe either you need to change your definition of immutability, or accept that your idea of immutability is different to that of most other developers, who *would* say that `string` is immutable.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Er, for reference types, that "something" is anything except for reassigning to the reference (so `x = ...` doesn't count). If you want to be pedantic, then for reference types, `object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)` should still be true when `x.Equals(y)` is false, in order for us to call it mutable. (I also agree that `string` is immutable, and I'm pretty sure it's consistent with my definition.) Does it make sense now?

Comment: You don't assign to a *reference*, you assign to a *variable*. The reference is the value of the variable. So now you've changed the rules for reference types, but not for value types. If you're allowing assignment for value types, then that would mean there's no such thing as an immutable value type *by definition*. That doesn't seem a terribly useful definition to me. Additionally, your new check using reference equality says nothing about immutability - it says that the `Equals` implementation is broken. (It violates the symmetry part of the Object.Equals contract.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: *"then that would mean there's no such thing as an immutable value type by definition"* -- yes; not in C# (it's obviously not a supported feature), but there is in C/C++. The definition is quite "useful" because it lets you reason about the same functionality in different languages. If the definition of immutability suddenly changed when going from C to C# then it wouldn't make sense, would it?! As for `ReferenceEquals`'s symmetry, I don't understand what you think is broken -- `x.Equals(y)` and `y.Equals(x)` always return the same value.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sorry, I mean the reflexive property. `x.Equals(x)` should always return true... which means that if `ReferenceEquals(x, y)` returns true, then `x.Equals(y)` should always return true. But in terms of mutability, I don't think it's useful to try to mean the same thing between fairly significantly different type systems here, at the cost of losing a useful distinction *within* one type system. I think so long as one understands the limitations of value type immutability in .NET, it's still a useful concept.

Comment: @JonSkeet: `x.Equals(x)` is always true in my example, when do you think is that false? Regarding the type systems, they *aren't* different -- and this is pretty obvious in C++/CLI, which represents reference types via `Type^` notation, so that it's **explicitly** marking them as some kind of a "pointer". With that notion, it's pretty obvious that `Type^` then just behaves the same way as `Type*` would, in C -- *and the difference between `Type` and `Type^` would be explicit*. This is why I excluded `=` for reference types. C# just changes the syntax, but the semantics are the same.

Comment: @JonSkeet: In other words, I excluded `=` for reference types because the referenced (pointee) type is not the same as the referencing (pointer) type, so reassigning to the pointer doesn't mean the referenced (pointee) is mutable. The fact that C# can't distinguish the two explicitly doesn't mean there isn't a difference between them -- there is, and C++/CLI (which is obviously another .NET language) shows the difference quite explicitly. So whatever the definition is, if it applies to all of .NET, then it should apply to C++/CLI too. My definition does, but yours doesn't.

Comment: I think we're going in circles here. You said: "If you want to be pedantic, then for reference types, object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) should still be true when x.Equals(y) is false" - which makes no sense to me. I don't think we're going to agree on this (my definition *does* make a distinction where yours doesn't, for example - quite the reverse of what you're saying) so we're probably best just leaving it.

Comment: @JonSkeet: `y` was a `Clone()` of the old `x`, that doesn't violate the reflexive property in any way that I can see. As for your definition, it doesn't work with C++/CLI (or C or C++ or what have you) and it's not consistent with what immutability means in computer science in general, but if you're happy with it then you're happy with it I guess.

Comment: @Mehrdad: If `y` was a `Clone()` of the old `x`, then how would `object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)` be true at all? Look again at what you've said: a situation where `object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)` returns `true`, but `x.Equals(y)` returns `false`. How is that *not* a broken implementation of `Equals`?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ugh, I made a mistake while correcting [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457905#comment23627157_16457938), sorry about that. What I **meant** to say was this, if you'll allow me to correct it: For reference types, if you can make a `Clone()` of `x` called `y` that is subsequently able to satisfy `!x.Equals(y)` **without** ever reassigning the references `x` or `y`, then the object referred to by `x` is mutable; if this is *never* true for objects of a given type, then the type is immutable. So this means `string` and `object` are immutable.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Okay, that makes more sense. But now if we change the test to just say "without using the assignment operator on x or y" then it becomes a useful differentiation between mutable value types and immutable ones (by my terminology), no?

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, and here's why. The person who really cares about immutability is a **reader**, not a writer. Let's say I have `struct Point { public readonly int x, y; public Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; } }` and I also have `var arr = new Point[1]`. Let's say I pass `arr` to you. If you ask me, "Is `Point` immutable?", then you're asking me, *"can you guarantee me that if I read `arr[k]` (for the same k) at two different points in time, I will always receive equal values?"* Obviously, the answer is no -- so `Point` is mutable. But you'd be saying yes, so your notion is wrong.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's the case for *any* array of *any* type though, because all arrays are mutable. The array elements can change for reference types or value types. I really think we're best calling it a day though. I very much doubt that either of us will persuade the other.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, arrays are mutable. I'm talking about the type of the **element**, not the array itself. And it's *not* the case for arrays of ref types. That's why I went through the whole business of `Equals` versus `ReferenceEquals`. If it was an array of `string`s, then you could **not** change the `Equal`ity of any element without modifying *the reference* itself -- i.e. in order to make `arr[k].Equals` return false, you **have** to make it refer to a *different* object, making `ReferenceEquals` return false, too. So the array is mutable, yes, but that doesn't imply the object is mutable.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Again, think about how it works in C++/CLI, which is also a .NET language: over there, we would have `array<string^>^`. This means `array<string^>^` (the reference to the array), `array<string^>` (the array itself), and `string^` (the reference to the string) being mutable. But `string` is immutable, because when you have a `string^`, there's no way to change its `Equal`ity without also changing its `ReferenceEqual`ity. If I changed substituted `string^` with `int`, and `string^` was mutable, then that implies `int` is mutable, which is consistent between value and reference types.

Comment: @Mehrdad: As I said, I don't think we're getting anywhere. Let's cut it short here.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm not sure *why* you insist "we're not getting anywhere" -- you haven't even considered what your definition of immutability means in C++/CLI, which is a perfectly valid .NET language -- but if you don't want to discuss it further then yes I agree, we *definitely* won't get anywhere, so see you later I guess.

Comment: @Mehrdad: We're not getting anywhere because you're certainly not going to persuade me to give up the notion of differentiating between mutable and immutable value types, and I'm not going to get you to change your opinion either. Nor is this an appropriate forum for this discussion. I can't comment on C++/CLI as I don't know it well enough, but I don't feel that invalidates the benefit of the differentiation I'm drawing. (Which is a *very* common one, btw. You'll see people recommending that value types shouldn't be designed to be mutable all over the place.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: *"you're certainly not going to persuade me to give up the notion of differentiating between mutable and immutable value types"*... well, if I'd known that you're so sure about that earlier I certainly wouldn't have even tried! As for people recommending that value types shouldn't be mutable -- yes, it's all over the place, but as far as I have seen, they're narrow-minded: ***none*** of them consider that their definitions of "immutable" (which is basically "has non-readonly fields") are inconsistent with other languages' -- *even including C++/CLI*, which is another .NET language.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I would regard the mutability of any non-static structure field which can ever hold a non-default value as being the same as the mutability of the storage location which holds that structure; other people seem to differ.  I think the difference in viewpoint stems from whether one views a structure as an "object", or as an aggregation of variables.  Those who are inclined to view everything as an object will regard `s=new Struct(2)` as creating a new instance of `Struct`, even though all it really does is mutate field `Value` of the existing one.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sometimes it is useful to define structures which behave as objects, and the .NET guidelines, including restricting mutation to full replacement, are good ones *for structs which are supposed to behave like objects*.  I think the disagreements stem from the fact that C# pretends that all structures are objects (even though non-boxed structures aren't), and thus everything should behave like an object, and everything which doesn't is defective.  Personally, I think what's defective is the C# notion that everything is an object; the CLI determines how things actually work...

Comment: @Mehrdad: ...and any language which claims things contrary to it is in error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a different *instance* of your `Struct`. You have not overwritten the `readonly` value of the original `Struct`. That is, the variable `s` has been assigned a `Struct` with `Value` of 1 and later on assigned a *different* `Struct` with the `Value` 2.

The point of `readonly` is to allow the value of a field to be set either during initialization or construction of the type, but not afterwords.

If you try:

```
static void Main()
{
    var s = new Struct(1);
    Debug.Assert(s.Value == 1, "Read-only field is 1");
    s.Value = 2;
    Debug.Assert(s.Value == 2, "Read-only field written!");
}
```

You will get a compiler error - "A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)".

Comment: It's in the exact same memory location though. Someone who referred to the object would see the field as modified. What do you mean by it being a different instance -- isn't it just a value type with some memory location?

Comment: @Mehrdad `What do you mean by it being a different instance ` I think he's referring to this: `s = new Struct(2);`

Comment: @Mehrdad - It is a _different_ object, as it is a `new Struct(2)`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's not an object, it's a value-type value. How would anyone else refer this? You've just got a local variable.

Comment: @Mehrdad See [Objects (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx).  Its not in the exact same memory location as its a different instance of `Struct`

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's quite easy to refer to it another way so that multiple people can see it -- just put it inside an array (or reference-type object). Now anyone who has a copy of the array reference will see the "read-only" field of that `struct` changing, which seems to negate its purpose...

Comment: @DGibbs: I think you took my question of "what do you mean by a new instance?" a little too literally. Yes, it says `new` and it's "different" to the person who wrote it because he obviously knows he said `new`, but to a **different** person who is accessing the same value (how is he supposed to know *how* the field changed?), it looks exactly the same as the old instance, with one of its fields modified. So there's no difference between modifying the "old instance" versus replacing it with a "new instance" -- the end result is impossible to distinguish for a reader.

Comment: @Mehrdad I understand that, but it's a different question? You originally asked: `What is the purpose of making a field readonly in C#? It doesn't actually seem to prevent modification of the field`. This clearly answers that question.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor or declaration is allowed to write to them, but no-one else.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): *"When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class."*

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly):

> A readonly field can be initialized either at the declaration or in a constructor.